# Retreiving the specific field in ebaysdk

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

```
api = finding(appid=ID_APP, config_file=None, siteid=GLOBAL_ID)
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords':search['search'],
                                              itemFilter':[
                                         {'name':'MinPrice' , 'value':'20',
                                         'paramName':'Currency','paramValue':'USD'},
                                         {'name':'MaxPrice' ,      'value':'22'}
                                                            ],
                                        'paginationInput': {
                                           'entriesPerPage': '5',
                                           'pageNumber': '1'
                                                                },
                                       'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest',                          
                                                            })
return response.dict()
```

in this code how can i get 5 items with only title,galleryURL,price without using loop?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: this code shows us items with full detail such as title,locations,currency,categoryid ,etc. I need only title ,galleryurl , price